# Using Cron for a weekly and monthly task

Tags: cron, cronexpression

Is there a crontab expression that will allow me to schedule a task to run weekly AND the first of each month? Of course, I could break these out into two separate lines:

```
15 3 * * 1,4 execute_task_weekly
15 3 1 * * execute_task_monthly
```

But if the 1st of the month happens to coincide with Monday or Thursday, then it will kick off that task twice. I'm sure I could put some code into the script I'm running and then just tell cron to run daily, but I would prefer to do it in cron, if possible.

Comment: At the risk of sounding a trifle dense; why do you want to run both weekly and once a month?

Comment: Good question! The task is to update a database table with historical information. We need the data month-to-date, and then at the end of each month, finalize the previous month's data and initialize the current month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the conversation we have had in comments, it sounds like your scheduled task is pulling double duty- performing one job each week and then a subtly different job at the end of the month. For that reason (as well as the fact that having scrutinised the documentation, I don't think you can do what you want to do), I would suggest having two different tasks/scripts and running them at the two different times.